# APP CRASH-Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Tags: android, memory-management, crash, adb, memcpy

As my app was crashed, while doing some memcpy(),
here is the call stack

```
08-14 16:01:11.209 F/DEBUG   (20611): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xffffffff7428d7f8
08-14 16:01:11.259 F/DEBUG   (20611): backtrace:
08-14 16:01:11.259 F/DEBUG   (20611):     #00 pc 000000000001c7e4  /system/lib64/libc.so (memcpy+116)
08-14 16:01:11.259 F/DEBUG   (20611):     #01 pc 0000000000532278  (strdup+76)
08-14 16:01:11.259 F/DEBUG   (20611):     #02 pc 0000000000496fec
```

Since I using a common pool to allocate the memory for source and destination in the strdup() and the strdup() is under n number of the loop. I am suspecting that whether memory overlap has happened. Can you please give some solution to solve this crash. (As the crash was randomly observed).

example: Where string is a structure has member of char * ptr and int len.

```
char* strdup(pool *pool,string *d,const string *s)
{
    if (d == s)
    return dst;

    if (s->len) 
    {
    d->ptr = (char*)pool_alloc(pool, s->len);
    memcpy(d->ptr, s->ptr, s->len);
    }
    d->len = s->len;
    return d;
}
```

Comment: `}  d->len = s->len;`Change to `d->len = s->len; }`

Comment: Can you please say, how it will work

Comment: What do you mean? Just change your code. Do a replace. Statement only should be executed if s->len. Put it in that block.